# Problem with adding a new line of text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(330.0),
child: AppBar (
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1D153B),
  title: RichText(
    text: TextSpan (
      style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
      children: <TextSpan> [
        TextSpan (text :'Makan Bang'),
        TextSpan (text :'Makan Bang'),
        TextSpan (text :'Makan Bang'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

The terminal says that "no named parameter with the name 'children'."
Is there any other ways for me to add a new line of text beside using the RichText widget?

Comment: maybe you missed a bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have two/three lines max before clipping title widget's bounds :

```dart
child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1D153B),
          title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('first line'),
                Text('second line'),
              ],
            ),
        ),
```

or you can use flexible space property of AppBar (background space) to add widgets :

```dart
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1D153B),
          flexibleSpace: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
              Text('example text'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```